# Weird invalid vector error from lpsolve55

Tags: python-3.x, list, constraints, lpsolve

I am currently trying to use `lpsolve55` (lpsolve  Python Interface version 5.5.0.9
using lpsolve version 5.5.2.11) to see if it gives a better performance than `PULP_CBC_CMD` for my Linear Programming (LP) problem.

However, I kept running into the weird error of Invalid vector, when I tried to add a constraint with a numeric list of length 230 (entries are of `dtype=float64`). I am not sure how to fix it, but when I read this documentation (https://web.mit.edu/lpsolve/doc/Python.htm), it does say something like "Matrices with too few or too much elements gives an 'invalid vector.' error." I don't think a list of length 230 should be called "too much elements." I did add a constraint successfully with a list of size 7800, in exactly the same manner. So I am not sure what is going on with `lpsolve55` package.

For example, the following line is successful:

```
lp.lpsolve('add_constraint', problem, coeffs, 'LE', per['max'])
```

where `coeffs` is a list containing 7000 floating numbers, and per['max'] is just another floating number.

The second constraint prompts the error `lpsolve.error: invalid vector.`

```
lp.lpsolve('add_constraint', problem, y, 'LE', rhs_max)
```

where `y` is a list of only 230 floating numbers, rhs_max is just another floating number

**Question.** Is it because `lpsolve55` is not designed to solve a large-scale LP problem with potentially 1000+ variables in the objective function?

I tried everything I could think of (e.g. using `np.array` rather than `list`, or try to replace `y` with `y[0:10]`). Nothing worked.

Comment: Anyone has any idea on how to make this work?